# Insert into DB with codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying to add new post into my db. I have Model, Controller and View created. Actualy im using rest api for this, but now I want to do it with pure php powerd. 
But After form validation is nothing. So when I try to post, nothuing happens. 
Here is my code.

Model:

```
// Create
function create($data) {
 // Insert data into DB
 $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
 return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function add() {
 if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {

   // Validation rules
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Titel', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('teaser', 'Teaser', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('full', 'Volltext', 'required');

   if (($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)) {
     $this->load->view('templates/backend/header', $this->data);
     $this->load->view('pages/backend/blog/add', $this->data);
     $this->load->view('templates/backend/footer');
   } else {
     if($this->input->post()) {
       $data = array(
         'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
         'teaser' => $this->input->post('teaser'),
         'full' => $this->input->post('full')
       );
       $this->blog_model->create($data);
       redirect(base_url().'blog/');
     }
   }
 } else {
   redirect('login');
 }
}
```

And at least my view:

```
<div class="uk-margin-top">
<?php $attributes = array("class" => "uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-form  uk-margin-lage-bottom", "id" => "add-form", "method" => "post");
        echo form_open("/backend/blog/add", $attributes); ?>


  <div class="uk-form-row">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large title redactor-box" name="title" placeholder="Beitragstitel" type="text"
           value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>"/>
    <span class="uk-text-danger"><?php echo form_error('title'); ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="uk-form-row">
  <label class="uk-form-label" for="teaser">Teaser</label>
  <textarea id="teaser" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large teaser redactor-box" name="teaser" data-uk-htmleditor></textarea>
    <span class="uk-text-danger"><?php echo form_error('teaser'); ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="uk-form-row">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="body">Body</label>
    <textarea id="full" name="full" rows="4" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht"
          value="<?php echo set_value('full'); ?>"></textarea>
    <span class="uk-text-danger"><?php echo form_error('full'); ?></span>
  </div>

  <div class="uk-form-row">
    <a class="uk-button uk-button-success" data-action="add-post">Submit</a>
  </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

So my problem is, when I click on my submit button - nothing. Maybe you can show me where my problem is.

Thank you!

Comment: You can remove `if($this->input->post()) {/**/}` block and set `$data` and model call into else block of form_validation check which already checks $_POST itself. And for solution, move link (<a href>) try with input or button for submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your controller, I think you are missing the form helper and validation library. I have included other comments in the code, but try this:

```
public function add() {

// you need to load these in:
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

// I am assuming ion_auth is working, however, I would try this code without
// this conditional statement
if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {

    // Validation rules
    // Make sure the second parameter is right. I think Titel should be Title.
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Titel', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('teaser', 'Teaser', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full', 'Volltext', 'required');

    // added a triple === instead of == for stricter type checking
    if (($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)) {

        // I am assuming $this->data is a property of your controller class
        $this->load->view('templates/backend/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('pages/backend/blog/add', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('templates/backend/footer');

    } else {

        // Check if the form was submitted via $_POST method
        if($this->input->post()) {

            // I removed your $data array and created it in the model.
            // I added a condition here to check if the data was successfully inserted
            if ($this->blog_model->create()) {
                redirect(base_url().'blog/');
            } else {
                // output an error message or redirect
            }

        }

    }
} else {

    redirect('login');

}
```

}

For your model, I think you were not passing any data to your model. Try the following for your model:

```
public function create()
{
    // you need to pass an array of data or an object
    // the array key corresponds to your db table column
    // the array value corresponds to your views input field names
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'teaser' => $this->input->post('teaser'),
        'full' => $this->input->post('full')
    );

    // returns true or false
    return $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your and @Tpojka's method and now its working! Thank you guys! You saved my day.